# Set up SPF: encountered SPF Permanent Error

Tags: spf

Our DNS is managed through Microsoft.  I need to set up a new record to allow a new website to send email. Here is what I did.

1) I set up the following SPF record
host: `subdomain`
value: `v=spf1 ip4:xxxx ip6:xxx include:subdomain.domain.com -all`

2) There is an existing SPF record
host: `@`
value: `v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com -all`

When I test it, I got the following error

```
PermError SPF Permanent Error: include has trivial recursion: include:subdomain.domain.com
```

Can someone tell why and how to fix it?

Also for the new SPF if I add the host as @, how should I add the value?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup multiple SPF records. Right?

You can't have multiple TXT entries for SPF. You have to combine all.

```
v=spf1 ip4:xxxx ip6:xxx include:spf1.sampledomain.com include:spf2.sampledomain.com include:spf3.sampledomain.com -all
```

Comment: Thank you very much! yes, I combined them and the recursion error is gone. thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You are setting up the SPF record for the domain: subdomain.domain.com

You should not be including a recursive lookup (with include) of itself in its own record. I believe you intended to set up the record

```
v=spf1 ip4:xxxx ip6:xxx a:subdomain.domain.com -all
```

So it looks up the DNS A record for the subdomain. The other thing of note is that this SPF TXT record needs to be at the subdomain.domain.com level of the structure, not applied directly to the domain.com level.